# A unique circle with 3 points proof

Tags: geometry, circles

I have prove the theorem: There is only one circle passing through three given non-collinear points in both geometrical and algebraic ways.
THere is one question that I just have no idea with.
'the accuracy and limitations of this technique"

I dont know what to write...! thank you

Answer (score 7):

In the geometrical way, you can use the fact that in a circle, if you draw a line between any two points in the circle and you bisect that line, the bisected line will go through the center of the circle. So if you have three points, you can draw two bisects and they will intersect at a unique point, which will be the center of your circle. To determine its radius, just compute the distance from your center to any of your three points.

In the algebraic way, you have three points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3,y_3)$ such that 
$$
(x_i - a)^2 + (y_i - b)^2 = c^2, \qquad i=1,2,3
$$
which gives you three equations in three unknowns, namely $a,b,c$ (the coordinates of the center $(a,b)$ and the radius $c$). You can use one of the equations to reduce the other two to linear equations and solve the linear system to get the coordinates $a$ and $b$. Once you have those two, any of the three equations will give you $c$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: we need to non-co-linearity to prove the uniqueness of the solution(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LinearSystemofEquations.html)

Comment: Better yet, think of this as a system of *linear* equations $$x_i^2 + Ax_i + y_i^2 + By_i + C = 0\,, \quad i=1,2,3\,,$$ and check that the coefficient matrix is nonsingular if and only if the three points are noncollinear.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee : The non-colinearity will appear when one tries to solve the linear system. I was assuming OP needed only a hint. I gave him one.

Comment: There are many ways to solve linear systems. At some point you just have to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, you can prove it this way:

Since the three points are noncollinear, you can construct perpendicular bisectors through each of the line segments formed between the points. And since the perpendicular bisectors all intersect at one point, that means those points are all equidistant from that intersection point. Therefore there is a circle.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

A few years late but I'll give the algebraic approach a try.

Proof:

A circle's equation in the Cartesian plane can be represented as:
[ x^2 + y^2 + ax + by + c = 0 ]

Where $(a, b)$ is the center of the circle in the translated coordinate system, and $c$ is a constant.

For three points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$, we have the system of equations:
\begin{align*}
x_1^2 + y_1^2 + ax_1 + by_1 + c &= 0 \\
x_2^2 + y_2^2 + ax_2 + by_2 + c &= 0 \\
x_3^2 + y_3^2 + ax_3 + by_3 + c &= 0
\end{align*}

We arrange this system into matrix form $Ax = b$, where:
[ A = \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
x_3 & y_3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

x = \begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c
\end{bmatrix}

b = \begin{bmatrix}
-x_1^2 - y_1^2 \\
-x_2^2 - y_2^2 \\
-x_3^2 - y_3^2
\end{bmatrix}

Matrix $A$ is derived from the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ in the circle's equation, and vector $b$ contains the square terms moved to the other side of the equation.

For the matrix $A$ to have a unique solution for $x$, it must be nonsingular, which means $\det(A) \neq 0$.

But if the points are non-collinear, the determinant of matrix $A$ will not be zero because the points do not lie on a straight line, and thus they do not satisfy a linear relation of the form $ax + by + c = 0$. The non-singularity of matrix $A$ implies that there exists a unique solution for $x$, and hence there is a unique set of coefficients $a, b,$ and $c$ that define a circle passing through the three non-collinear points.

Therefore, there exists a unique circle determined by the three given non-collinear points.

Answer (score -3):

In the algebraic way, you have three points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3)$ such that
$(x_i−a)^2+(y_i−b)^2=c_2,i=1,2,3$
$(x_i−a)^2+(y_i−b)^2=c_2,i=1,2,3$
which gives you three equations in three unknowns, namely $a,b,c$ (the coordinates of the center $(a,b)(a,b)$ and the radius $c$). You can use one of the equations to reduce the other two to linear equations and solve the linear system to get the coordinates $(a,a)$ and $(b,b)$. Once you have those two, any of the three equations will give you cc.

Hope that helps,

Comment: `In the algebraic way, you have three points ...` This, and the rest of your "answer" is just a copy/paste from @PatrickDaSilva's answer from almost $4$ years ago, with only some stutter added. Surely there must be better ways to use/waste your time.